# Trying to invoke web service but getting an error

Tags: c#, web, soap, service, weather

I am trying to run below web service.

http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

When I enter zip code and press the invoke button,

[image]

I got the following error.

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

I am finding solution over the internet.

Comment: Is this a webservice you have source code access to? The SQL connection in their is broken. But if you don't have access then you should contact their support.

Comment: this is a login issue related to your sql server instance. Make sure you are entering the correct credentials and have access to the server

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Is this a webservice you have source code access to? I dont have source code to access.